# Error: Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names. in R dataset

Tags: filter

I am having error in running the script below. i need to filter the data for the countries Italy and Argentina in the indicator3 data frame.

[image]

```
#ItalyAng<-indicator3%>%
  # filter(country==Italy)
ItalyAng<- filter(indicator3,country %in% c('Italy','Argentina'))
```

Error in `filter()`:
! Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.
Backtrace:

1. dplyr::filter(indicator3, country %in% c("Italy", "Argentina"))
2. dplyr:::filter.data.frame(indicator3, country %in% c("Italy", "Argentina"))
   Error in filter(indicator3, country %in% c("Italy", "Argentina")) :

Comment: Please don't post same thing multiple times

Answer (score 0):

you could have two columns with the same name.
you can check it

```
which(duplicated(names(indicator3)))
```